# Eclipse THyM with Cordova default application XML errors

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, cordova

I'm currently playing with `Cordova` and just started wondering if I could develop from my `Eclipse Neon`.

Downloaded lastest `JBoss tools` and installed them on my Javascript Eclipse Neon, so I could use the new Hybrid mobile development functionality.

Created a default Hybrid mobile (Cordova) Application Project using the new project wizard. Added Android platform (`cordova-android@5.2.2`).

Eclipse builds and configures the new project but some errors regarding XML validation appear. I can run this sample app either on my android device or the cordova simulator. It runs and displays OK, but errors are still marked on eclipse code.

**These are the errors I get:**

```
cvc-attribute.3: The value 'loglevel' of attribute 'name' on element 'preference' is not valid with respect to its type, 'null'.    defaults.xml    /Test/platforms/android/cordova line 25 XML Problem

cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'loglevel' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[AllowInlineMediaPlayback, AndroidLaunchMode, android-maxSdkVersion, android-targetSdkVersion, AppendUserAgent, BackgroundColor, BackupWebStorage, ChildBrowser, CordovaWebViewEngine, DefaultVolumeStream, DisallowOverscroll, EnableViewportScale, EnableWebGL, ErrorUrl, FullScreen, GapBetweenPages, HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar, HideMousePointer, InAppBrowserStorageEnabled, KeepRunning, KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction, LoadUrlTimeoutValue, LoadingDialog, LogLevel, MediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay, MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction, Min/Max Version, Orientation, OSXLocalStoragePath, OverrideUserAgent, PageLength, PaginationBreakingMode, PaginationMode, PopupBlocker, SetFullscreen, ShowTitle, Suppresses3DTouchGesture, SuppressesIncrementalRendering, SuppressesLongPressGesture, TopActivityIndicator, UIWebViewDecelerationSpeed, WebSecurity, WindowSize, WindowsDefaultUriPrefix, WindowsStoreDisplayName, WindowsStoreIdentityName, WindowsStorePublisherName, WindowsToastCapable, deployment-target, target-device, windows-phone-target-version, windows-target-version]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.   defaults.xml    /Test/platforms/android/cordova line 25 XML Problem

cvc-attribute.3: The value 'loglevel' of attribute 'name' on element 'preference' is not valid with respect to its type, 'null'.    config.xml  /Test/platforms/android/res/xml line 22 XML Problem

cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'loglevel' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[AllowInlineMediaPlayback, AndroidLaunchMode, android-maxSdkVersion, android-targetSdkVersion, AppendUserAgent, BackgroundColor, BackupWebStorage, ChildBrowser, CordovaWebViewEngine, DefaultVolumeStream, DisallowOverscroll, EnableViewportScale, EnableWebGL, ErrorUrl, FullScreen, GapBetweenPages, HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar, HideMousePointer, InAppBrowserStorageEnabled, KeepRunning, KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction, LoadUrlTimeoutValue, LoadingDialog, LogLevel, MediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay, MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction, Min/Max Version, Orientation, OSXLocalStoragePath, OverrideUserAgent, PageLength, PaginationBreakingMode, PaginationMode, PopupBlocker, SetFullscreen, ShowTitle, Suppresses3DTouchGesture, SuppressesIncrementalRendering, SuppressesLongPressGesture, TopActivityIndicator, UIWebViewDecelerationSpeed, WebSecurity, WindowSize, WindowsDefaultUriPrefix, WindowsStoreDisplayName, WindowsStoreIdentityName, WindowsStorePublisherName, WindowsToastCapable, deployment-target, target-device, windows-phone-target-version, windows-target-version]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.   config.xml  /Test/platforms/android/res/xml line 22 XML Problem
```

This is de the default `config.xml` file generated by Eclipse:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="org.adn.test" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Prueba</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the
        deviceready
        event.
    </description>
    <author email="thym-dev@eclipse.org" href="http://www.eclipse.org/thym">
        Eclipse.org -
        Thym
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
</widget>
```

And this is the `defaults.xml` file, also autogenerated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 distributed with this work for additional information
 regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 specific language governing permissions and limitations
 under the License.
-->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        id        = "io.cordova.helloCordova"
        version   = "2.0.0">

    <!-- Preferences for Android -->
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
</widget>
```

**Cordova version installed on my computer is `6.3.1`** but I'm not certainly sure that it's the same Eclipse is using...

I've been searching but can't find any tutorial or guide about Eclipse THyM. Not even in their eclipse project's page. It's being tough solving this. I don't really understand why would I get errors in an auto-generated basic sample project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just found the answer to my own question:

Regarding the Cordova docs, the `name` attribute for what Eclipse generates as `loglevel` must be `LogLevel`. That typo caused the errors to appear, exactly as the errors describe.

Link to Cordova's doc on Config.xml [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/#preference). Just scroll down until you find `LogLevel`. Just in case somebody finds this useful.

I don't really know if there's anyway to report the `Eclipse THyM` team this issue or it is even worth reporting.

Comment: Soo it seems like a bug in Eclipse Thym then? Can you please report it to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Thym ?

Comment: @Mickael it's done, this is the reported bug URL. My first :D
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=500281